# Apache 2.4.7 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: apache, ubuntu, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to install the overpass api as a web server with apache (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/install)

Here is my 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ExtFilterDefine gzip mode=output cmd=/bin/gzip
DocumentRoot /root/osm-3s_v0.7.4/html

# This directive indicates that whenever someone types http://www.mydomain.com/api/ 
# Apache2 should refer to what is in the local directory [YOUR_EXEC_DIR]/cgi-bin/
ScriptAlias /api/ /srv/osm3s/cgi-bin/


# This specifies some directives specific to the directory: [YOUR_EXEC_DIR]/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/srv/osm3s/cgi-bin/">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            #SetOutputFilter gzip
            #Header set Content-Encoding gzip
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg
LogLevel warn

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
```

However when I try to run the command:

```
http://175.33.148.57/api/interpreter?data=%3Cprint%20mode=%22body%22/%3E
```

I get the 403 Forbidden error.

I have already done

`chmod 777 /srv/osm3s/cgi-bin/`

But nothing seems to work.

Please help, Ive been stuck on this for 3 days now! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Status error code `403` `forbidden` isn't a file system access violation. It is an Authorization violation. Please check if your directory has `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Shouldn't the `DocumentRoot` and `Directory` be the same folder?

Comment: I dont think it does have a .htaccess file, I havent seen one located on the server. Where should it be/ what sound it look like? 

I dont think the file directory needs to be the same as its not the static html I want to access, it's a file called 'interpreter' located in /srv/osm3s/cgi-bin/

Comment: Is `interpreter` file readable-executable? Is `selinux` in enforcing mode? If `selinux` is enforcing, make sure that apache is allowed to access the folder and allowed to read and execute `interpreter` file.

Comment: seems you need `SetHandler` there. `SetHandler cgi-script`

Comment: Verify file permissions recursively (Unix based systems). chmod -R 755 /srv/osm3s/ (on root dir). Directories at least should be 755; files should be 644

Comment: did you brought it to work? I'm struggling with the exact same problem. I tried all permission options but its not working.

Comment: I did get it working @Kingalione , see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved this problem for anyone who might have a similar one:

It seemed the problem came from where I installed the overpass installation ($EXEC_DIR).

So I had to change the install directories to:

```
$EXEC_DIR       /var/www/osm/
$DB_DIR         /var/www/osm/db/
$PLANET_FILE    /var/www/osm/planet.osm.bz2
$REPLICATE_DIR  /var/www/osm/rep/
```

Giving the resulting `default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ExtFilterDefine gzip mode=output cmd=/bin/gzip
    DocumentRoot /root/osm-3s_v0.7.4/html

    # This directive indicates that whenever someone types                         http://www.example.com/api/ 
    # Apache2 should refer to what is in the local directory         [YOUR_EXEC_DIR]/cgi-bin/
    ScriptAlias /api/ /var/www/osm/cgi-bin/


    # This specifies some directives specific to the directory: [YOUR_EXEC_DIR]/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/var/www/osm/cgi-bin/">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            #SetOutputFilter gzip
            #Header set Content-Encoding gzip
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I tried and tried but couldn't get it working with the old dir. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

Replace:
Allow from all 
by 
Require all granted

```
<Directory /www/mysite>
    Allow from All
</Directory>

<Directory /www/mysite>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
try this as it is. don't add Order allow,deny or others

AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py 
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```